# Class not enhanced despite maven plugin for build-time enhancement

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa

At runtime I get the error:

pom.xml's build:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>JPA Enhance</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- I tried with and without this -->
                <persistenceXmlFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
                <toolProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>addDefaultConstructor</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>enforcePropertyRestrictions</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </toolProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also tried it with:

```
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/User.class</includes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: i wonder what logging of that enhancement process tells you ...

Comment: @NeilStockton When I run the maven "task" to enhance the classes manually, then it works and enhances the class. But when I simply run the main build, that is never called.

Comment: so are the enhanced classes overwritten, after enhancing? or are you using some different classes at runtime? aka debug what is used when

Comment: @NeilStockton I think it's not even calling that plugin. I'm using IntelliJ and when I select that "enhance" task and right-click and choose "Run Before Debug", then it works! Why wouldn't it get called by default?